# .animate() will not change element styles back to original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have written a function that simulates the update of a 'live' element. It picks an element at random and then animates it using `.animate()` and `.effect()` from the jQuery UI library. However, once the animations have finished the element should return back to it's original color, but for some reason this doesn't happen. Find below the code and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyjay7rf/).

```
var decider = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 1
var original = $('.tile:nth-child(' + decider + ')').css('background-color');
var a = $('.tile:nth-child(' + decider + ')');

$(a).animate({
    backgroundColor: 'green'
}).effect('shake', {
    distance: 5,
    times: 1
}, 1000).animate({
    backgroundColor: original
});
$(a).hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: original
    }).finish();
});
```

Comment: I'm wondering something btw, you define -var a- with $(element) and then use it with, once again, $.  "a.animate" is not ok ?

Comment: I see no problem with that, as a is just $('.tile:nth-child(x)')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a timing issue there.
Every time you are running `run()`, it checks for the `original` color depending on the DOM. But what if the DOM color is still green when checked, and not `original`?

It's a good practice to use `animate()` callback function for stuff that happens after animation finishes. That way you know that animation has finished and at it's right state, instead of using a arbitrary time value.

```
function run(){
    var decider = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    var original = $('.tile:nth-child(' + decider + ')').css('background-color');
    var a = $('.tile:nth-child(' + decider + ')');

    $(a).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }).effect('shake', {
        distance: 5,
        times: 1
    }, 1000, function() {    
        // first animation finish, start second animation
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: original
        }, 1000, function () {
           // second animation finish, re-run
           run();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

replace your **run** function with the given one.

```
function run(){
    var decider = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    var original = $('.tile:nth-child(' + decider + ')').css('background-color');
    var a = $('.tile:nth-child(' + decider + ')');

    $(a).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }).effect('shake', {
        distance: 5,
        times: 1
    }, 1000).animate({
        backgroundColor: original
    });
    $(a).hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: original
        }).finish();
        clearInterval(myVar);
    });
    var myVar = setTimeout(run, 1000);
}
```

this must help you :)